# Checked checkbox remain through pagination using load JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem here using .load() AJAX/jQuery when I use it in pagination. the status of my checkbox will not remain when I go to another page.

For example I checked 2 items in page 1 then when I go to page 2 to select another item then when I go back to page 1 to test if my checked item remain checked. unfortunately it became unchecked maybe because of the .load(). Is there an alternative to use aside .load() to remain my checkbox checked?

Here is my code for .load() ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load
    $('body').on('click', '.paginate_click', function(e){
    var ticked = [];
    $('.tick:checked').each(function(){
      ticked.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });


    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); 

    $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); 
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){
       ticked.forEach(function(val, i){
          $(val).prop('checked', true);
       });
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});     
});
</script>
```

and here is my checkbox code

```
echo "<div id='a'><input type='checkbox' class='tick' name='items[$i]' id='$i' value='". $item['ItemID'] ."' >".$item['ItemName']."</div>";
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: wat will I do? @Veerendra

Comment: You have asked the same question 21 hours before also

Comment: I have commented yesterday on your question giving you the logic to maintain the checkbox have you tried it?

Comment: Yes! because it did not works thats why I asked again @Veerendra can you please help me?

Comment: Can you please give me an example @Veerendra?

Comment: you need to create a small javascript function which will update your array in the session and will add the id of checked box and once the page is loading you need to check in the loop whether the loop checkbox id is there in session or not if its there you can show it checked.

Comment: Can you give me an example of code? @Veerendra im so sorry because im newbie in javascript

Comment: you can add the checked values in array and save it to cookie

Comment: @MaryRoseS.Cruz hope my answer help you, let me know if problem persist with the code on the logic :)

Comment: Hi @Veerendra your code really helps me i have a problem with the $_SESSION['checked'] in my html part the error said it was undefined but i declared it on my ajax file. How to fixed it?

Comment: @MaryRoseS.Cruz you can define it blank on the index file or before the html starts in the listing file.

Please accept the ans if it helped you :)

Comment: Thats the only problem that I had I cant get the checked item and save it to the session @Veerendra

Comment: @MaryRoseS.Cruz at the index please first check $_SESSION['checked'] exist then dont declare if not then declare it as keeping it open without condition will declare it on each reload and the checked values will be reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will take time so i have outlined the full logic for you, you just need to add the basic syntax now and it will work for you.

**The html part**

```
 // check while load its in the checked session array or not 
    $checked='';
    if(in_array($item['ItemID'],$_SESSION['checked']))
    {
        $checked = 'checked';
    }
    echo "<div id='a'><input type='checkbox' ".$checked." class='tick' name='items[$i]' id='$i' value='". $item['ItemID'] ."' onchange='check_status(this.value)' >".$item['ItemName']."</div>";
```

**The Script logic**

```
<script>
function check_status(check_id)
{
    // make a ajax call here and send the box value(itemid) to php 
}
</script>
```

**The ajax php file**

```
// get the id of checked box and add to session

// check if id already in the session if yes then its a uncheck call so remove it from session array by searching
// into the array using array_search and then unset the index of array 
// reset the array index using array_values 


//else add to the array 
  $_SESSION['checked'][]=/*add the id each time here*/;
```